# UIComponent's width and height have no effect on Sprite

Tags: apache-flex

Given this code:

```
var circle:Sprite = new Sprite();

circle.graphics.beginFill(0xFFCC00);
circle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 20);

var uiComp:UIComponent = new UIComponent();

uiComp.x = 100;
uiComp.y = 100;

uiComp.measuredHeight = 0;
uiComp.measuredWidth = 0;

uiComp.addChild(circle);

addChild(uiComp);
```

Why does changing the width and height of uiComp not affect the Sprite? Wouldn't UIComponent provide Sprite with a Graphics object, which limits that area where Sprite can draw?

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the other thread, use `unscaledWidth` and `unscaledHeight` as the bounds for drawing.

Comment: @JTt iirc, these two were answered back-to-back. Luckily @flexwheel has asked only two questions and finding the [other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611980/where-in-the-framework-is-the-graphics-object-passed-around-to-achieve-drawing) was easy.

Comment: @JTt understand that. In my defense, the answer to the current question is complete without referring to the other thread.