# Where in the framework is the Graphics object passed around to achieve drawing?

Tags: apache-flex

I'm trying to understand how the Flex framework draws objects (Button, Label, Image, etc.). The Button class seems to draw itself by addChild()ing its ProgrammaticSkin. However, where in the framework is the Graphics object being passed around in the hierarchy to achieve the drawing. I want to get to the level of 2D API.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single global graphics object in flash/flex. Every Shape and Sprite (UIComponent is a  Sprite) has a `graphics` object of type [Graphics](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Graphics.html) that can be drawn on. In a flex app, programmatic drawing should be done in the overriden [updateDisplayList](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#updateDisplayList()) method of the component. You should use the component's `unscaledWidth` and `unscaledHeight` as its bounds while drawing on it.

Comment: The object that overrides updateDisplayList uses the graphics instance to draw. How is the value for the graphics instance set, and where? Tried to look in the layout code, but was unsuccessful.

Comment: That happens internally - most probably in the constructor of the `Sprite` class - we don't have access to that code.